# extglob default behavior for `(..|..)`?

Tags: bash, shell

## Note: This Q may be bogus.

I'm currently unable to replicate the results described below, see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44233989/6136214) for details.

---

An [anonymous editor suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16254561) replacing this `bash` code `echo ${s//+(*\/|.*)}` with `echo ${s//(*\/|.*)}`, (where `shopt -s extglob; s=/the/path/foo.txt`), and both produce the same output "*foo*".

It works the same for that data, (on *Bash v4.3* anyway), but it is the same?  The manual...

```
 man bash | grep -B 1 -A 20  'several extended pattern matching operators'
```

...doesn't seem to shed any light here:

```
   If  the  extglob  shell  option  is  enabled  using the shopt
   builtin, several extended pattern matching operators are rec‐
   ognized.   In  the following description, a pattern-list is a
   list of one or more patterns separated  by  a  |.   Composite
   patterns  may  be  formed  using one or more of the following
   sub-patterns:

          ?(pattern-list)
                 Matches zero or one  occurrence  of  the  given
                 patterns
          *(pattern-list)
                 Matches  zero  or more occurrences of the given
                 patterns
          +(pattern-list)
                 Matches one or more occurrences  of  the  given
                 patterns
          @(pattern-list)
                 Matches one of the given patterns
          !(pattern-list)
                 Matches  anything  except one of the given pat‐
                 terns
```

So, given *no* leading char of {`?`,`*`,`+`,`@`, or `!`}:

1. Are any of functions provided by those leading operators identical to the function of `(..|..)` in `bash`?
2. If not, and `(..|..)` does something different in `bash`, what *does* it do?
3. Do any other shells, (i.e. `zsh`, `ksh`, etc.), provide a working `(..|..)`?  (And if so, how do those shells document it?)

Comment: "If it isn't documented, it doesn't exist" -- or at least, there's no guarantee made that it will continue to exist in the future, or is otherwise something other than a transient accident of implementation. Unless someone can find a documented reference for this idiom, I would strongly advise against its use.

Comment: Minor point: the `.` doesn't need to be escaped in either case; it's not a pattern metacharacter.

Comment: The second just echo's the original string for me on `GNU bash, version 4.2.46`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, If it matters, I have _not_ done the suggested replacement `s/+(/(/`.

Comment: @123, Please try this:  `shopt -s extglob ; s=/the/path/foo.txt ; echo ${s//+(*\/|.*)} ; echo ${s//(*\/|.*)}`

Comment: @agc, prints `foo \n /the/path/foo.txt`

Comment: Removing the `+` sign makes the whole story to fail at bash 4.4 and bash 4.2 (see this online test with bash 4.2: https://cg5.tutorialspoint.com/embed/453/UDJLh1vP). We need to keep the `+` in order extglob to be in effect (PS: `|` is used as `OR`)

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou, Thanks for running that test.  Re "*PS: `|` is used as OR*": it certainly is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a "dummy answer", as I'm **unable to replicate the results** of my initial tests.  At present both with online testers, as [noted by *George Vasiliou*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229937/extglob-default-behavior-for?noredirect=1#comment75475933_44229937), and my own online tests, and tests on my home system, `echo ${s//(*\/|.*)}` prints only `/the/path/foo.txt`.

A few theories as to why that might be:

1. My initial Q may have been posted in error, perhaps a copy & paste error, a mistake with `bash` history, and an careless reading of the results made it only *seem* that that the results were genuine.  Ordinarily I'd just scroll back on the `lxterminal` screen buffer and check, thus either confirming or debunking the Q.

   Unfortunately, due to some recent upgrades, my laptop's *suspend* feature has become rather balky these last few days, and the needed scrollback buffer was lost to a failed un-suspend.  Nor can I find that portion of the command history corresponding to the time when this Q was first posted.
2. One of the recent upgrades may have changed either `bash` or some dependency of `bash`.  This seems unlikely, as a look at `grep bash /var/log/dpkg.log` shows `bash` hasn't been upgraded since *5/24*, well before this Q was posted.
3. Some significant config option was changed between when the Q was posted and now.

Therefore, I'd prefer to err on the side of caution, and mark this Q as **answered** as soon as SE allows -- which can always be changed back if anyone does manage to replicate the Q results.